# How can I populate the reference field & with the extra field using with $addFields in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the document, Here I need to populate all objects & add the extra field

```
"last_message": "Hello"
```

the above one

/* 1 */

```
{
             "_id": "5b5067ce15c4e462fd43732a",
                "users": [
                    "5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fb",
                    "5b1625f762368179e1e4549b",
                    "5b0d3c00b426ea12ec0f6e3a"
                ],
                "group_name": "Group 1",
                "created_at": "2018-07-19T10:28:30.967Z",
                "last_updated_at": "2018-07-19T10:28:30.967Z",
                "__v": 0

            },
```

/* 2 */

```
     {
            "_id": "5b5067e915c4e462fd43732c",
            "users": [
                "5b0d4c5ec47e6223a08af5fb",
                "5b0d3c00b426ea12ec0f6e3a"
            ],
            "created_at": "2018-07-19T10:28:57.084Z",
            "last_updated_at": "2018-07-19T10:28:57.084Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    }
```

I used with $addField in aggregate function, its only added. populate function not working. how to handle this one.

Comment: Can you add your aggregation query and the expected response to the post ?

Comment: Post your aggregation query to get the question resolved